# Does JWPlayer support Subresource Integrity?

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am using a cloud hosted player from JW (content.jwplatform.com/libraries/xxxx.js).

I'd like to add the integrity hashes to check if this resource is valid. But I am not sure if the source can change when there's for example an update of the JW player.

Any ideas if this can happen?

**About SRI**

SRI is a new [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) that allows web developers to ensure that resources hosted on third-party servers have not been tampered with. Use of SRI is recommended as a best-practice, whenever libraries are loaded from a third-party source.